# Lookup fields will be rendered as a list of checkboxes inside iphone safari web browser , instead of being rendered as a select list

Tags: 2013, development, lookup-column, form

I am working on an issue tracking list which have a lookup column named “Related Issues”, which is rendered as a select list inside IE on desktop browser as follow:-

[image]

But when I access the list from my iphone using safari browser, then the lookup column was rendered as a group of checkboxes, instead of the above select list.

So can anyone advice , how I can have the same select list inside my iphone safari browser ? as we have around 100+ related issues and having them as checkboxes look very non-user friendly .

Comment: Good question. This field is rendered as checkboxes in other mobile devices also, when mobile device channel is used.

Comment: @ECM4D so is there any way to control this ? because if we have many items inside the look-up column, then it i will not be user friendly to display all the items as checkboxes..